# Selenium execution stops when screen is locked

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I can execute my Selenium scripts without any issues if the screen is not locked. As per our organization policy, our system will be locked automatically after 3 minutes of inactivity (but system will never sleep or hibernate).

The problem is that the test execution stops because of `NoSuchElementException` sometimes after the screen is locked. This exception occurs randomly on different elements after the screen is locked.

So I cannot run my tests unattended I guess. Selenium test should run without any problem regardless the screen is locked. I run the tests on Google Chrome on Windows machine. Is there any work around for this issue?

I could use some scripts to prevent the screen from locking, but it's not allowed in the organization because of security reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502696/will-my-selenium-script-in-execution-stops-if-my-computer-goes-on-sleep-mode-hi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my selenium script in execution stops if my computer goes on sleep mode/ hibernate mode ?in my absence? i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502696/will-my-selenium-script-in-execution-stops-if-my-computer-goes-on-sleep-mode-hi)

Answer (score 0):

I am in a same situation and about to try the following

1- Installed a VNC Server on Windows and in the setting select "ALLOW LOOPBACK CONNECTIONS ONLY" - to address security concern

2- open vnc viewer from that system and connect to localhost

and then try running the test.. additionally you can create a localuser for this specific purpose and apply local policy to it like (donot lock the system for this specific user , and user can't take rdp connection etc)

let me know if this works for you? or any other solution if you have.

Comment: Did you try to do this yet? And if so, what was the result?

Comment: I am happy to inform you that this solution works perfectly fine... One more thing go to control panel and in power option. Select Never for turn off display